# How to use Bayes to calculate event repetition probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am having trouble understanding how to apply Bayes the problem of calculating the probability of a significant weather event (earthquake, hurricane, flood, fire, etc.) repeating $r$ times.

I understand the concept of "Return Period" and it's probabilistic interpretation using a Poisson distribution.  For example, what's the probability of a 500 year hurricane occurring twice within a 50 year period?

Start with the counting rate, $\mu$:

$$\mu = \frac{m}{n+1}$$

$m$ = number of recorded occurrences

$n$ = number of years on record

$$\mu = \frac{1}{500+1} = 0.0020$$

Take the Poisson distribution

$$P_t(r) = {\frac{(\mu t)^r}{r!}}{e^{-\mu t}}$$

$r$ = number of occurrences we are calculating for = 2

$t$ = time period = 50

$\mu$ = counting rate = 0.0020

$$P_t(2) = {\frac{(0.0020 \cdot 50)^2}{2!}}{e^{-0.0020 \cdot 50}} = 0.0045$$

Enter Bayes:

$$P(H|A) = \frac{P(A|H)P(H)}{P(A)}$$

I am confused about how to apply this.  Is the prior probability $P(H)$ what I calculated above $P_t(2) = 0.0045$ or the simpler ratio $\frac{1}{500} = 0.0020$?  I think it's the latter.

I think the conditional probability $P(A|H)$ is what I calculated above $P_t(2) = 0.0045$.

Which leaves me with $P(A)$

I'm really confused at this point.  I'd appreciate a shove in the right direction.

Comment: Bayes's formula only applies for conditional probabilities. Which is the CONDITIONAL probability you want to calculate ? Which is the event known to have happened ? And which is the event for which you want to calculate the probability ?

Comment: Say we have an oddly shaped stone with six numbered sides such that the number 6 comes out once every 500 rolls on average after having recorded 10,000 rolls.  We roll the stone and the number 6 comes out.  I am after the probability of the number six coming out again within the next 50 rolls given that it just came out.

Comment: If we assume independence of the rolls, the probability that the $6$ appears within the next $50$ rolls does NOT depend on whether it just appeared or not.

Comment: Just use the (estimated) probability of $\frac{1}{500}$. The probability that at least one of the next $50$ rolls gives a $6$ is then $$1-(\frac{499}{500})^{50}=0.09525$$ You need no Bayes's formula here.

Comment: I simplified in my comment in order to get the general structure across.  You'll note that my question talks about natural disasters. Rather than rolling an irregular dice the idea here is to try to determine the probability of another major event in someone's lifetime once a major event occurs.  For example, an 8.0 earthquake might be a 1 in 200 year event. What's the probability of it occurring again during someone's lifetime, say, 50 years if we had an 8.0 today. I wondered about this as I thought about hurricane Harvey. What's the probability of a similar event within a lifetime.

Comment: The Poisson-distribution you mentioned should already be the proper method for rare events. But to point this out again : We have no reason to assume that the probability for a further event of this kind within some time changes if we have observed it already. Additionally, the problem of rare events is that it is hard to estimate the average time until such an event happens. In the case of the hurricanes, it is well possible that they are not so rare anymore. If we cannot assume the independence, predictions are very difficult.

Comment: Yes, I realize what you are saying.  This was more of an academic exercise rather than anything else.  I can see cases where having a significant event happen can influence the time before that level of an event might repeat.  In the case of an earthquake the release of accumulated stress means it might be a while until that extreme level of stress accumulates again.  Not sure about hurricanes.